# webdriver-manager fails to install selenium standalone

Tags: selenium, webdriver-manager

Experts,

I have following configuration

```
nvm - 0.33.0
node - 7.5.0
npm - 4.1.2
webdriver-manager - 12.0.6
```

I am behind a corporate proxy and I use cntlm. when I run the following command

```
webdriver-manager update --standalone --ignore_ssl --verbose --proxy="http://localhost:3190/"
```

I get following output

```
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
[15:08:27] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[15:08:27] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[15:08:27] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
(node:4132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: response status code is not 200
(node:4132) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[15:08:28] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.33.zip
[15:08:28] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/ua70vv/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.33
[15:08:29] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[15:08:34] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.19.0.tar.gz
[15:08:34] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/ua70vv/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.19.0
```

I see there is a warning.

After this when I try to run "webdriver-manager start", I still get error complaining following

```
E/start - Selenium Standalone is not present. Install with webdriver-manager update --standalone
```

Please suggest what is the error here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
--ignore_ssl                Ignore SSL certificates
--proxy                     Proxy to use for the install or update command
```

Like `webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl`

This will solve your problem.

Comment: well.. it solved the problem, but I checked the certificate of the site which gave me the triuble and which seems to be hosted on AWS (???); the problem is that the ceriticate has as certification authority something like "INVALID", and to tell the truth I feel uneasy about using the webdriver-manager updated in such a manner..

Answer (score 0):

seems the standalone.jar download site not avaiable.  https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/

you can use java cmd to start selenium server, save below content into a start-selenium-server.cmd file on window, and change the versions and driver_home to yours. Double click it to run.

```
set standalone_version=3.4.0
set chromedriver_version=2.32
set geckodriver_version=v0.19.0

set driver_home=C:\Tool\npm-global\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=%driver_home%\chromedriver_%chromedriver_version%.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=%driver_home%\geckodriver-%geckodriver_version%.exe -jar %driver_home%\selenium-server-standalone-%standalone_version%.jar -port 4444
```